# returned more than 1 value error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have issued with my sql server query. When I run this code, I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I have tried a many ways but it still errors - how can I solve it?

Comment: Get rid of the correlated subqueries altogether. They are performance killers and should not be used in production code if at all possible,. It is simply a poor programming technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty straight-forward. Your subquery returns more than 1 row. This is not allowed because of how queries work. Things in the `SELECT` clause cannot define multiple rows, this must be in the `FROM` clause.

There are many ways to solve this, some of them:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(field) ...)
SELECT (SELECT field ... GROUP BY field)
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 field ...)
```

The problem is that **all of the above** (with the possible exception of the `GROUP BY`, which may not work) **will** quite possibly **return** unwanted data - **only a single row for each row in the original query**.

You may want to use `XML PATH` to **concatenate all these values** into a single cell.

Or if you're happy with **multiple rows, use `JOIN` instead**:

```
SELECT someAlias.field
...
JOIN table as someAlias ON someAlias.somefield = someothertable.someotherfield
```

**As in:**

```
SELECT A.MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID
FROM   T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG
       JOIN T_TR_CLOSING
         ON T_TR_CLOSING.CLOSING_ID = T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG.CLOSING_ID
       JOIN T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG
         ON T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG.CLOSING_ID = T_TR_CLOSING.CLOSING_ID
       JOIN T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG AS A
         ON A.EMP_ID = T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG.EMP_ID
WHERE  T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG.CLOSING_ID = '1'
```

Comment: actually i have many field query buat only this field i'm getting error, i've edited a complete query above your answer, this field query except bold query is good working.  by the way thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: @ElyinTrifena There is probably more than 1 matching row. I'd probably try `GROUP BY MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID` in the subquery (it will only discard duplicates, so will "safely" fix things, or may still not work) or the `JOIN` (for multiple rows). Otherwise you'll need to actually check what it returns to see why there is more than one match (the easiest would be to do this with a `JOIN`).

Comment: **(SELECT MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID FROM T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG WHERE T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG.EMP_ID = T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG.EMP_ID) AS CHECKROLL_ID**,
should i add a **GROUP BY MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID** in a select
such as
**(SELECT MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID FROM T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG WHERE T_PR_EMPLOYEE_LOG.EMP_ID = T_PR_CHECKROLL_WISE_LOG.EMP_ID GROUP BY MR_EMPLOYEE_CHECKROLL_TYPE_ID) AS CHECKROLL_ID,**
thanks so much for your help, that's really help me

Comment: @ElyinTrifena Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: it still doesn't work with group by, or i put group by in wrong location?

Comment: @ElyinTrifena `JOIN` will *work*, but maybe not as expected - it will add rows for each match in the other table, if this is not what you want, you'll have to clarify what output you want.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's solved... i just add top 1 and use a group by statement...